# Zero sequence query in boolean array

Tags: time-complexity, range-query, segment-trees

I have a large array of bits of length $N$.
The query $f(k, m)$ means "find $kth$ zero in the array and the next $m-1$ zeros after it", $k \in [0, N-1], m \ll N$

Currently I use a segment tree over the bit array and my approaches were:

- use [kth zero search procedure](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html#counting-zero-search-kth) $m$ times in $O(m \log{N})$
- use the same kth zero search procedure but with divide-and-conquer approach:

  1. find the first $0th$ and the last $(m-1)th$ zero while also finding their LCA subtree
  2. find $(m/2)th$ zero in the LCA subtree
  3. recursively do 1. and 2. for both $0th$ and $(m / 2)th$ pair and $(m / 2)th$ and $(m-1)th$ pair

  this improves time greatly if the zeros are clustered but the worst time is still  $O(m \log{N})$
- maintain a link to the next zero for each member of the array, this gives $O(\log{N} + m)$ time but complicates array updates and requires additional $O(N)$ memory

I want any solution with better than $O(m \log{N})$ time.
I'm ready to switch to any other data structure if necessary.

Besides the aforementioned query the requirements are:

- spatial complexity is $O(N)$
- initialization in $O(N)$
- update after a single bit in array is flipped in $O(logN)$

Comment: what operations does your data structure need?

Comment: There are occasional updates of the bit array. The data stucture should be able to update itself after a single bit changed in $O(log N)$ or better.

Comment: Please don't respond with more information in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and contains all necessary information, and so people don't need to read the comments to understand what you are asking.  Thank you!  I've provided similar feedback in the past: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/153435/#comment322876_153435, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/151051/#comment317584_151051

Comment: @D.W. the question is updated

Comment: Do you allow allow adding links to the zeroes to organize them in a linked list ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust even if a linked list is allowed, it will cost $O(n)$ to restore its links after a single random bit flip.